# Is there a way to convert ExFAT to UDF?

Tags: filesystems, udf, exfat

I couldn't assume that a file system can be converted to another in-place until I bumped into `btrfs-convert`. I want to convert my 700GB/1TB `ExFAT` partition to `UDF`. Google has no answer for that.

Is there a way to convert ExFAT to UDF?

Comment: I would back up the content (files and directories) to another drive (for example as a tarball), and then create the UDF file system and finally restore the content ((files and directories) into the UDF file system. Please notice that there are few tools for UDF (and not much documents) compared to other file system. The following link may add some details, ["Full compatibility with Linux, Windows and MacOS"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952673/how-do-i-copy-a-file-larger-than-4gb-to-a-usb-flash-drive/952706#952706)

Answer (score 0):

Humane interpreted answer:

> Is there a way to convert ExFAT to UDF [in-place]?

No. It's generally a risky and fraught process to convert one filesystem to a completely different filesystem in place and the tools to do it are only made in exceptional circumstances when developers are trying to persuade people to the new filesystem automatically (think ext* -> BTRFS or Microsoft's FAT32 -> NTFS).

Pedantic answer to exact original title:

> Is there a way to convert ExFAT to UDF?

Yes:

- Create the new filesystem somewhere else and copy the files into it
- Tar all the files up, store the tar in a temporary filesystem elsewhere, destroy the old filesystem, create the new filesystem in its place and untar the files to it.

Obviously anything that involves deleting data is done at your own risk, make sure you have working backups etc.